# Rails 7 dry-struct add attribute from method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry-struct

I'm using dry-struct for non-model class `Payout` - it's basically structured hash response from API call.

module Customer
class Payout < Dry::Struct

```
attribute :amount, Types::Integer
attribute :reference, Types::String
attribute :settlements, Types::Array

def fetch_settlements
  CustomerApi.fetch_settlements_by_reference(platform_merchant_id, reference)
end
```

end
end

Is it possible to set `attribute :settlements` by the `fetch_settlements` method ? I was trying something like:

```
attribute :settlements, Types::Array.optional.default(feth_settlements)
```

but I'm getting an error of

> undefined local variable or method `fetch_settlements

Comment: can you please change method as `def self.fetch_settlements` and try once ?

Comment: @AmolMohite it appears that fetch_settlements requires instance values e.g. `reference` so making it a class_method will not work.